# How to trigger ActivityAware override method onAttachedToActivity()?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I need a reference to the activity for my plugin. According to [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration#uiactivity-plugin), I actually need to implement ActivityAware, and to get a reference to the activity, it is provided by `onAttachedToActivity` override function. How do I trigger this override function? I actually looked up [this doc](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/activity/ActivityAware.html) but it's not quite clear how to trigger it as I haven't seen any sample code anywhere. It says

> This method can be invoked in 1 of 2 situations:
>
> This ActivityAware FlutterPlugin was just added to a FlutterEngine
>   that was already connected to a running Activity. 
>   This ActivityAware
>   FlutterPlugin was already added to a FlutterEngine and that
>   FlutterEngine was just connected to an Activity.

My code looks like this:

```
public class MyPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware {
Activity activity;
@Override
public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
  // TODO: your plugin is now attached to a Flutter experience.
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
  // TODO: your plugin is no longer attached to a Flutter experience.
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding activityPluginBinding) {
    activity = activityPluginBinding.getActivity()

  // TODO: your plugin is now attached to an Activity
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
  // TODO: the Activity your plugin was attached to was
  // destroyed to change configuration.
  // This call will be followed by onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges().
}

@Override
public void onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(ActivityPluginBinding activityPluginBinding) {
  // TODO: your plugin is now attached to a new Activity
  // after a configuration change.
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromActivity() {
  // TODO: your plugin is no longer associated with an Activity.
  // Clean up references.
}
```

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: haven't got the solution yet

Comment: I added an answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the following abbreviated implementation. You implement the `ActivityWare` interface and then get the activity via `activityPluginBinding.activity`

`class ProPayFlutterPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware`

```
override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activityPluginBinding = binding
        initializeCardReaderDependencies(activityPluginBinding.activity)
}
```

```
    private fun initializeCardReaderDependencies(activity: Activity) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Initializing card reader dependencies")
        SDKManager.initialize(activity.application)
        Terminal.initialize()
        cardReaderController = CardReaderController.getControllerFor(BBPOSDevice::class.java)
        val meaningfulMessageListener = CardReaderEventStream(cardReaderController)
        cardReaderNotificationChannel.setStreamHandler(meaningfulMessageListener)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.startLockTask()
        }
    }
```